# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, design, graduation

Pretty straightforward question:

What should **Workplace.SE** make their logo and site design? Any ideas?

Comment: Fairly simple and professional IMO, more like [UX.SE] than [RPG.SE] but I don't have specific ideas right now

Comment: Anyone else thinking Dilbert meets XKCD?

Comment: @Chad I also thought Dilbert but couldn't think of how to incorporate it stylisticly

Comment: I have been chucking over the though of stiky-hair boss :p

Comment: While the bulk of our questions, at least in the beginning, will be focused on the IT world and Cubicle-land, we shouldn't design the site to obviously exclude other, non-office, non-IT workplaces.

Comment: @JacobG in the West "work", especially "professional" work simply evokes the office-based work environment of carpeted walls, sticky notes and binders. In addition, less-office oriented work related items tend to veer far too job-specific. Oil cans, plungers and medical lasers all mean work to some people, but not 99% of people.

Comment: @Chad I was thinking of plagiarizing Office Space. :)  "Work Sucks." :)

Comment: @Karlson I think gold badges should be red staplers :)

Comment: @Chad I'll second that. :)  That would be really cool.  Black Staplers, White Staplers , and Red Staplers for the Badges!

Answer (score 10):

Our tabs could be like those Manilla folder tabs:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Somehow, somewhere, there should be a water cooler in it.

Comment: I think a watercooler icon would be perfect.

Comment: The Watercooler really should be our Chatroom name

Comment: Problem is it's a busy item for a background image. Possibly as a part of an icon or logo though.

Comment: And lo and behold, ['tis done](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2331/362)!

Comment: and it came out that this was [true](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) like that

Answer (score 5):

Work always makes me think of those cork bulletin boards. Perhaps we can incorporate that somewhere?

[image]

Comment: This should totally be the background of our community bulletin...if it can be made readable

Answer (score 3):

To be unoriginal, our badges could be coffee mugs:

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote this if someone delivers me coffee every time I earn a badge.

Answer (score 3):

Our badges could be more like Neck-Tie icons, since tie represents a formal work environment.   Much like the following icon in Gold, silver and bronze color.

[image]

Comment: Not sure ties would work well in 16px

Answer (score 3):

How about watches for badges?

There was the tradition started many decades back of giving an employee a gold watch for retirement. While we don't want folks to retire, it's topical, and may be a good fit?

> Disclaimer: I failed art in high school and was told I draw wrong by my teacher.

Sample:

[image: Watch Badges]

May need to touch up to insides of the watches too like this:

[image: Version 3]

Though having the hands constantly stopped at 9am may not be what we're aiming for. 3pm perhaps?

Comment: I like it, though that watch tradition seems to have died a while ago. Unless it confuses people, let's do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking something along the lines of an office building motif: stylized cubicle furniture logo,  or perhaps an building with "The Workplace" on a sign?

I have all the artistic sense of a star-nosed mole though.

Answer (score 2):

I think when i think of workplace -i think of the "office chair" -

[image]

It of course the most critical element for us to function in the office; but sometimes "Chair" is also extended with Connotations of "Position" in the hierarchy in the company. The bigger the chair you have - the more influential you are really! Sometimes the biggest guys are called "Chairman" or "Chairperson".

But yet, i am getting a bit clueless on how this can be translated as part of theme.

Answer (score 1):

A new thought, why not have paper clips as the badge icons?

I can't think of any workplace representative icon better than a paper clip!

It's been part of the workplace for decades, first in physical form, then again as Clippy the paper clip in word.

Answer (score 0):

Handshake for a logo, like this:

[image: http://vector-magz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/handshake-icon2.jpg]

Or [water cooler](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111/168), like this:

[image: http://www.aperfectworld.org/clipart/office/water_cooler.gif]

or like this:

[image: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13353604#13353604]

See also: **[Chatting various ideas of site logo at Water Cooler](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/chatting-various-ideas-of-site-logo-at-wate-cooler)**